# Delegate a Web App permissions to use Power BI API

Tags: powerbi, azure-security, powerbi-api

We are creating a web app that will use the PowerBI API to export paginated reports as PDF.
I can do this with my own account and a PPU license.

I will need to ensure the Web App can do this on behalf of a user of the web app.
All the documentation points to using "embedded" but Im unsure if thats what i need.

I thought I could create the web App by give it an app registration in AD.
This app registration would then get access to the workspace, but it will also need a license.

What is the way to set this up correctly, so the app accesses power bi via an app registration or managed identity?

Comment: Are you sure this is working currently with only a PPU license? From Microsoft Power BI Rest API documentation for [Reports - Export To File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file): `Limitations: Premium Per User (PPU) is not supported.` Is your currently working report in a premium (not PPU) workspace? Microsoft appears to have some conflicting info on this specific topic (paginated report export via API with PPU license). So just wanting to confirm your situation.

Comment: In their [Power BI Premium Per User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-per-user-faq#considerations-and-limitations) documentation they say `The export API for PPU is available for paginated reports, with a limit of one call every 5 minutes, per user. Power BI reports are not supported.` If you are truly using that functionality within a PPU workspace, can you confirm it is limited to only one call every 5 minutes?